# Apply KMeans Clustering on subdivided Google Earth Engine image and store resulting cluster points

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, google-earth-engine-python-api

I am looking to perform an analysis on an image stored in Google Earth Engine (EE) by first dividing the image into small, equal-sized squares. I intend to apply a K-Means clustering algorithm (or a density-based clustering algorithm) on each of these small squares. Once the clustering is completed, I want to export the cluster points for further analysis.

I have successfully divided my image into equal-sized squares using a K-Means segmentation algorithm by setting the cluster size to 1. However, I am not sure if this is the most appropriate method for achieving this task. Additionally, I am facing difficulty in utilizing the segmentation results and iterating over them to apply K-Means Clustering on each square individually. I am a new user to Google Earth Engine. How can I proceed with my problem?

[image: Segmentation KMeans]